# Detect what Debian APT repositories are installed in a device using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, debian, apt

Hello, world. I'm developing an iOS Debian APT GUI for jailbroken iOS 12 devices. It is supposed to be an alternative to the well-known Cydia and Sileo.

The problem is that I need to show the installed repositories in the device, then if the user taps on one of them, display how many packages are in that repository, and then when a user taps on one of them, display an HTML, CSS and JS depiction.

How can I get all that data using **Swift**?

One of the ways I came up with is to use `apt-cache policy > ./result.txt` to write the results to a text file, and then, using Swift, read the file and generate the UI based on that. I wonder if there's a more efficient and easier way to accomplish that.

Also, I'd be targeting iOS, so obviously Swift doesn't allow me to use NSTask because it is supposed that all the iOS apps are Sandboxed.

Thanks in advance.

By the way, If I'm wrong in something, please correct me as I want to learn.

**EDIT**: Swift uses `Process`, not `NSTask`, sorry.

**EDIT**: I've discovered that Jailbroken iOS devices do not use `apt`, instead they use `dpkg` in order to understand `.deb` files.

Even though, I still need to get information from `dpkg` to detect how many repositories are installed.

Any help is grateful

Comment: If you are writing a non-App Store app for jailbroken devices, the idea of sandboxing shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, but I'm using Swift, and as it isn't supposed to be allowed to run commands in iOS, the compiler gives me an error: `NSTask is not available in Swift`, so I can't compile the app, even though later the app would run perfectly as the NSTask in jailbroken devices is allowed.

Comment: In Swift, it's `Process`.

Comment: Ok, well, thanks, that fixes the problem of running commands, but, how can I accomplish the main question: `Detect what Debian APT repositories are installed in a device using Swift`.

Thanks for answering